# Send email using wordpress plugin on behalf of someone with their permission

Tags: email, smtp

I have seen a few sites that send an email on behalf of a user, however when the email comes through it appears only as if its come from the user. For example contact forms on websites.

I am looking to do the same thing but obviously with the users permission. Is this possible to do in Wordpress or similar services available that won't go to the spam/junk folder?

Ideally the from/replyto email address should appear from the user and not get blocked i.e go through the right servers as long as I have their permission.

Comment: No, that generally isn't possible nowadays: things like SPF and DKIM restrict who can send email purporting to originate from a given domain in a widely trusted way. You can always send it from your own email address but set a Reply-To for the original user, and you can set a 'sent on behalf of' address too I think, but you can't spoof the From address.

Comment: This is going to get your server blacklisted as either a source of spam or as a malicious/hacked server. 99% of servers will reject the messages before they even arrive at the destination